# How do I fix index out of range when index is in range

Tags: python, kivy, kivy-language

When I run this program it says " self.buttons[1].bind(on_press=self.on_click) IndexError: list index out of range " but the element I want to access is still in range. How do I fix that?

```
import kivy
from kivy.app import App
from kivy.uix.boxlayout import BoxLayout
from kivy.uix.widget import Widget
from kivy.uix.button import Button
from kivy.graphics import Color

class LandingScreen(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LandingScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.buttons = [] #we will add references to all buttons here

        for x in range(4):
            self.buttons.append(Button(text='button ' + str(x+1), size_hint=(0.5, 0.5), pos_hint={'x': .2, 'y': .4}))
            #make a reference to the button before adding it in
            self.add_widget(self.buttons[x])
            self.buttons[1].bind(on_press=self.on_click)


    def on_click(self, instance):
        print('clicked')

class SplashApp(App):
    def build(self):
        return LandingScreen()

if __name__ == '__main__':
    SplashApp().run()
```

Comment: Lists in python are indexed from 0. Try `self.buttons[0].bind(on_press=self.on_click)`

Comment: If the index is at 0 it works but it doesn't work if I change the index to 1,2 or 3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Remove the indentation of that line so that it is not part of the loop:

```
class LandingScreen(BoxLayout):
    def __init__(self, **kwargs):
        super(LandingScreen, self).__init__(**kwargs)

        self.buttons = [] #we will add references to all buttons here

        for x in range(4):
            self.buttons.append(Button(text='button ' + str(x+1), size_hint=(0.5, 0.5), pos_hint={'x': .2, 'y': .4}))
            #make a reference to the button before adding it in
            self.add_widget(self.buttons[x])
        self.buttons[1].bind(on_press=self.on_click)


    def on_click(self, instance):
        print('clicked')
```

Answer (score 1):

Did you mean `self.buttons[x].bind(on_press=self.click`?

`range(n)` goes from 0 (inclusive) to n (exclusive). In the first loop, there was one item in the buttons list, but you were accessing the second element.

Comment: I mean if I change the index to 1,2 or 3 it doesn't work only if the index is at 0 then it will work

Comment: The goal is to bind each button to the function as you make them, yes?

Comment: No, forget about the bind  event, I want to change the color of the second button,  but it is not working, please look at the code again

Comment: The change I suggested will allow your code to run. If you wanted to change the color of the second button you should add after the loop: `self.buttons[1].background_color = (0,0,205,1)`

Comment: Thanks so much, it is now working. But please one more thing what if I want to change the position of a button using the same index how will I do that

Comment: Done, but please how would I change it position

Comment: I'm not sure, you might want to make a new question for that